# Adding Date to Excel using Open XML

Tags: excel, openxml

I would like to insert Date value to excel file using Open XML.

Here is my code sample.

```
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value.ToString());   
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Date);
```

Comment: And what happens? Do you get an error? If so: **what** error? Is the value just not added to the resulting Excel sheet? Do you get an error when trying to open the resulting Excel sheet?? You gotta help us help you here!!

Comment: I see first part of Date. eg 24/01/2010, I see 24 in the cell.

Comment: Closed? Why? I agree the problem could have been described better but if you knew what this is about you would agree it is a real question for which there exists a real answer!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the DataType should be omitted!

I was having the same prob, but just setting the CellValue did the trick!

```
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value.ToOADate().ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer and sharing with you all...

Just add cell as we do..

```
 Cell cell =new Cell(){ cellReference=A1 }; //Or other necessary details

 //Add value to cell in Double Format  then convert it into string using ToString()
 cell.cellValue = new CellValue(DateTime.Now().ToDouble().ToString()); 

 //Set the data type as Number
 cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);

 //Give its StyleIndex = 5 (default style index of date)
 cell.StyleIndex=5;
```

Here I have used

```
cell.StyleIndex=5;
```

which is By Default Style Index of date in Excel. So no need to add all the external styylesheets

Enjoy :)

Comment: I was not able to make this work and apparently others had problems with it too. See: [Writing Date Value in a cell using Open xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556061)

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for us:

```
c.CellValue = new CellValue(datetimeValue).ToOADate().ToString());
c.DataType = CellValues.Number;
c.StyleIndex = StyleDate;
```

Set the DataType to CellValues.Number and then be sure to format the cell with the appropriate style index from the CellFormats. In our case we build a stylesheet within the worksheet, and StyleDate is an index into the CellFormats in the stylesheet.

Comment: It's interesting that you quoted this code (back in 2012) in two StackOverflow threads, but didn't show what "StyleDate" actually looks like, so readers won't actually be able to use or learn from your code !

Comment: @MikeGledhill Exactly. It's infuriating