# Writing Date Value in a cell using Open xml

Tags: c#, openxml

I need to write a date in cell using date type using Open XML.
Can you please tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer and sharing with you all...

Just add cell as we do..

```
 Cell cell =new Cell(){ cellReference=A1 }; //Or other necessary details
 cell.cellValue = new CellValue(DateTime.Now.ToOADate().ToString()); 

 cell.StyleIndex=5;
```

Here I have used

```
cell.StyleIndex=5;
```

which is By Default Style Index of date in Excel. So no need to add all the external styylesheets

Enjoy :)

Comment: there isnt even a function DateTime.Now.ToDouble

Answer (score 1):

> So no need to add all the external stylesheets

I could not get it to work without the stylesheet.

I used [This Blog post](http://polymathprogrammer.com/2009/11/09/how-to-create-stylesheet-in-excel-open-xml/) to get it working.  Stylesheets need Font, Border, Fill, DifferentialFormat and TableStyle sections in addition to the CellStyleFormat and CellFormat sections needed to use a date.

```
private static Stylesheet CreateStylesheet()
    {
        Stylesheet ss = new Stylesheet();

        Fonts fonts = new Fonts(new OpenXmlElement[]
        {
            new Font
            {
                FontName = new FontName { Val = "Calibri" },
                FontSize = new FontSize { Val = 11 }
            }
        });
        fonts.Count = (uint)fonts.ChildElements.Count;

        Fills fills = new Fills(new OpenXmlElement[]
        {
            new Fill
            {
                PatternFill = new PatternFill { PatternType = PatternValues.None }
            }
        });
        fills.Count = (uint)fills.ChildElements.Count;

        Borders borders = new Borders(new OpenXmlElement[]
        {
            new Border
            {
                LeftBorder = new LeftBorder(),
                RightBorder = new RightBorder(),
                TopBorder = new TopBorder(),
                BottomBorder = new BottomBorder(),
                DiagonalBorder = new DiagonalBorder(),
            }
        });
        borders.Count = (uint)borders.ChildElements.Count;

        CellStyleFormats csfs = new CellStyleFormats(new OpenXmlElement[] 
        {
            new CellFormat
            {
                NumberFormatId = 0,
                FontId = 0,
                FillId = 0,
                BorderId = 0,
            }
        });
        csfs.Count = (uint)csfs.ChildElements.Count;

        CellFormats cfs = new CellFormats(new OpenXmlElement[]
        {
            new CellFormat
            {
                NumberFormatId = 0,
                FontId = 0,
                FillId = 0,
                BorderId = 0,
                FormatId = 0,
            },
            new CellFormat
            {
                NumberFormatId = 14,
                FontId = 0,
                FillId = 0,
                BorderId = 0,
                FormatId = 0,
                ApplyNumberFormat = true
            }
        });

        cfs.Count = (uint)cfs.ChildElements.Count;

        ss.Append(fonts);
        ss.Append(fills);
        ss.Append(borders);
        ss.Append(csfs);
        ss.Append(cfs);

        DifferentialFormats dfs = new DifferentialFormats();
        dfs.Count = 0;
        ss.Append(dfs);

        TableStyles tss = new TableStyles();
        tss.Count = 0;
        tss.DefaultTableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9";
        tss.DefaultPivotStyle = "PivotStyleLight16";
        ss.Append(tss);

        return ss;
    }
```

Once the style sheet is in place you can then set StyleIndex.

```
cell.StyleIndex=14
```